# Session Lost in fragments Quickblox chat implementation

Tags: android, session, android-fragments, quickblox

I have implemented chat application that has 2 tabs, one is for CHAT HISTORY and other is for USERS using QUICKBLOX ANDROID API. But Session is getting lost when I start my app every time, so chat history is not shown at first. But when I create a chat with user and came back to CHAT HISTORY fragment the history is perfectly shown. I have debugged this many times but the session token required error came at first.

Please help me to find this solution.

Comment: Could you add some code example of how you're doing this ?

Comment: Yeah, and also post some logs to better explain your error